# Bootstrap/CSS: get text aligned left center

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I need your help.
I have a column where there is some text. This must be in the center but aligned as shown below.
I tried adding a

`display: inline-block; text-align: left`

but it does not work.

I should have as shown below:

```html
                              Other Lorem Stuff
                          > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                          > Consectetur adipiscing elit
                          > Aenean laoreet lectus nec risus 
                            malesuada auctor.
                          > Vestibulum pellentesque, ante sit 
                            amet congue tempus
```

note that when the writings go back, they go under the writing and not under the > symbol

This is code:

```css
.footsmall{
    background-color: #FFF8DC;
    top:-50px;
    right: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: left
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 position-absolute footsmall text-center p-3">
                <p class="fs-4">Other Lorem Stuff</p>
                <p> > <u>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</u></p>
                <p> > <u>Consectetur adipiscing elit</u></p>
                <p> > <u>Aenean laoreet lectus nec risus malesuada auctor.</u></p>
                <p> > <u>Vestibulum pellentesque, ante sit amet congue tempus</u></p>
            </div>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [flexbox container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) for each item.

```
  <div class="d-flex">
    <span>&gt;</span>
    <p class="text-decoration-underline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
```

See the working snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 p-3 text-center">
      <p class="fs-4">Other Lorem Stuff</p>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <span>&gt;</span>
        <p class="text-decoration-underline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <span>&gt;</span>
        <p class="text-decoration-underline">Consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <span>&gt;</span>
        <p class="text-decoration-underline">Aenean laoreet lectus nec risus malesuada auctor.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <span>&gt;</span>
        <p class="text-decoration-underline">Vestibulum pellentesque, ante sit amet congue tempus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note, rather than using display and text-align in your CSS you can just add the classes directly to your elements:

```html
<div class="d-inline-block text-start"> </div>
```

Instead of paragraphs, you could use an unordered list and change the marker style to the chevron you want.

```css
.custom-li {
    list-style-type: '> ';
}
```

```html
        <div class="col-3 footsmall text-center">
            <p class="fs-4 p-3">Other Lorem Stuff</p>
            <ul class="text-start custom-li">
                <li>
                    <u>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</u>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <u>Consectetur adipiscing elit</u>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <u>Aenean laoreet lectus nec risus malesuada auctor.
                </li>
                <li>
                    <u>Vestibulum pellentesque, ante sit amet congue tempus</u>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Is that what you were after? Having the text not end up below your line markers?